# Determine whether it a lock type( read or write)

Tags: java, locking

Is it possible to determine what a lock type is like whether read or write in a readWritelock in java?

I have a function like below

```
  public Table getTableLocked(final Lock lock) throws FactFinderException {
     boolean loadTable = true;
       // Get the current table instance
    TableManagementInfo table = TABLES.get(mapKey);

     return table.instance;
```

}

In this situation I am passing a Lock (ReadWriteLock) . I need to determine first what type of lock it is..whether read or write...any idea how it can be done..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to determine if you have a `ReadLock` or a `WriteLock`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock;

...

if (lock instanceof ReadLock) {
  System.out.println("Read");
} else if (lock instanceof WriteLock) {
  System.out.println("Write");
}
```

Having said that, I agree with Peter that there is probably a better way of achieving what you want to do without checking dynamically.

Comment: This may be the answer the OP is looking for. But it doesn't answer the OP's original question IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lock for read, write or read and write.  So there is no way to know if a Lock is one or the other because they are all the same.

Use of locks is typically static in code, so I don't believe there is a good reason to want to check this dynamically.

EDIT: For example you can use ReentrantReadWriteLock to support multiple reads with ReadLock and a single writer with WriteLock. This is a common pattern which explans the names.  However say you want multiple writers and single reader?  You can just use the ReadLock for writing and the WriteLock for reading.

When you perform a read or write you should know, and not have to check, what type of lock you are using. The lock must match the operation you are performing. no other option will give you correct behaviour.

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  See my answer.  I agree with you though that its tough to think of a good reason to check dynamically.

Comment: Good comment, see my edit as to why I don't agree.  There is not about the locks themselves which tie themselves to the operations you perform while holding those locks.

Comment: I agree with you there.  My objection is this part of your answer: "there is no way to know if a Lock is one or the other".  You CAN figure out if its one or the other, even if that distinction isn't very meaningful.

Comment: In what situation would you ever want multiple writers and one reader?

Comment: @mlaw, I can't remember but I have seen posters ask for this in particiular. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @dbyrne: To clarify, you can only figure it out *under constrained circumstances*. For example, if he is using some arbitrary instance that implements `ReadWriteLock`, there is no guarantee that its `readLock` is an instance of `ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock` (`ReentrantReadWriteLock` is not the only class that can implement `ReadWriteLock`, it just happens to be the only one in the standard library). Likewise, there is no guarantee that its `writeLock` is an instance of `ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock`.

Comment: To paraphrase @Adam and @dbyrne, you can determine which class the lock is and you can make assumptions based on the class and its name what it is for, but there is no way to know for certain what all Locks are used for.